# Why dont emojis and special characters display properly after html purification with PHP?

Tags: php, html, htmlpurifier

So I have a blog that allows users to write content in one location using TinyMCE. The content is then sanitized, validated, and stored in the database. It is displayed on a different page. Pretty standard. However, I am allowing users to use emojis and special characters. Before I store the body content I run it through HTMLPurifier and then I run it through HTMLPurifier a second time before display.

**This is the code for purifying the body content before the database**

```
//Purify the body HTML
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$news_data['body']['clean'] = $purifier->purify($news_data['body']['raw']);
```

The emojis appear as normal in the database but even outputting the raw data to the webpage, I get the same weird data (see screenshot)

**This is the display code:**

```
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$purified_body = $purifier->purify($row['body']);
$clean_body = html_entity_decode($purified_body, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

My output:
[image]

**So, why aren't my emojis and special characters displaying properly if they appear raw in the database correctly?**

**Edit:**
I checked and the database collation is set to *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*

Thanks!

Comment: In general, you shouldn't do  HTML sanitization when you're storing in the DB. It should only be done when you're displaying the data on a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content-Type header was set to charset=ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

This resolved the issue.